# How can I write a route to match on just an HTML file name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC 2 application that serves up static HTML files as an actionresult

```
Content(htmlString);
```

This HTML contains relative links within it. i.e. /absdk123.html?t1=somevalue&t2=someothervalue

What should my route look like to match these HTTP requests? I have tried this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              "LinkRoute", // Route name
              "{html}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Home", action = "ResolveLink"} // Parameter defaults
          );
```

At the action, "ResolveLink" the string parameter is always 'null'. How can I write a route to correctly handle these links?

```
   public ActionResult ResolveLink(string htmlFileName)
        {
            //test param
            return Content(htmlFileName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
       "LearningModuleLessonRoute", // Route name
       "{html}.html", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "ResolveLink" }// Parameter defaults
   );
```

This will actually match any request of format /{filename}.html.
I didn't realize that a file extension could be included in a route.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "LinkRoute", // Route name
                "{htmlFileName}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "ResolveLink"} // Parameter defaults
               );


public ActionResult ResolveLink(string htmlFileName)
{
   //test param
   return Content(htmlFileName);
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. Your route parameter is {html} and your action parameter is htmlFileName - they need to be the same ;)